Expanding the barotropic nondivergent PV equation: Which vector calculus property/identity to apply for dot product and del operator?
I am trying to expand the barotropic nondivergent potential vorticity (PV) equation [link]
$$\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial t} = -\vec{V} \cdot \nabla(\zeta + f)$$
where $\zeta$ is the relative vorticity, $\vec{V}$ is the horizontal wind velocity ($\vec{V} = \langle u,v \rangle$), and $f$ is the Coriolis parameter. I intend to expand it into two terms (i.e. "separating" the relative vorticity and Coriolis parameter) which, based on what I've read, should be expressed as follows [link],
$$\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial t} = -\vec{V} \cdot \nabla \zeta + v \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = -\vec{V} \cdot \nabla \zeta + \beta v$$
where $\beta = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$.
I wasn't sure on what particular property or identity in vector calculus should be applied to come up with that equation, but this is what I did:
$$\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial t} = -\vec{V} \cdot \nabla(\zeta + f)$$
$$\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial t} = -\vec{V} \cdot \nabla\zeta - \vec{V} \cdot \nabla f$$
$$\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial t} = -\vec{V} \cdot \nabla\zeta - \langle u,v \rangle \cdot \bigg\langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \bigg\rangle $$
Assuming $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0$ (since $f$ varies only in the north-south direction),
$$\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial t} = -\vec{V} \cdot \nabla\zeta - \bigg[u(0) + v \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\bigg] $$
$$\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial t} = -\vec{V} \cdot \nabla \zeta - v \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = -\vec{V} \cdot \nabla \zeta - \beta v$$
As you can see in this derivation, the sign of the second term in the right-hand side became negative instead of positive. Where did I go wrong? Which vector calculus property/identity must be applied for this situation of an equation having both a dot product and del operator?
Any response and additional insights on this are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

You didn't go wrong anywhere. The most reasonable explananation is that the $v$ in your link is defined to have the opposite sign as the $v$ in your post. It could also be that they are instead using the opposite sign convention for $y$. But there's no way for anyone to know without more context.
